# React root.js weights about 9MB

Tags: reactjs, foreman

Ok, so... I have this project where we are using a lot of components (as usual in every React project) but when we compile the project to see it in the browser (ie. `foreman start`) it takes a lot of time to load and also when it loads it creates a file that is very very large.

We don't know why this is happening, probably something that we messed up and we don't know yet.

I don't know which part of code you need to see to help me understand why this is happening. Let me know and I will give it to you.

Also, I wanna know if there is a way to prevent that file to be that large, as long as I know it should weight no more than 2Mb or something...

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The typical reason for such issues is not the amount of components you have made but rather the libraries you use. You can check what is the cause for a large bundle by first running

`webpack --json > stats.json`

and then installing and running [webpack bundle analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer)

`webpack-bundle-analyzer stats.json`

After this you need to start working on fixing the cause of the large size.

Normally that would depend on what the reason for large bundle size is..but the following methods will definitely help.

- [code splitting for react](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)
- [code splitting for webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/)
- Using [webpack's optimizations](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/)
- And, since sometimes tree-shaking doesn't work as well as it is expected to..you could change your imports from the style of

```
import {x, y} from 'library';
```

to

```
import x from 'library/x';
import y from 'library/y';
```

Which would ensure that if there are 10 exports from the library, then all of them dont get loaded... Only those that are needed do. For example, if you are using lodash,

```
import {debounce} from 'lodash';
```

will import the entire lodash library while

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';
```

will only import that particular file.
There are other ways to optimize your output (like [webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)) but that is dependent on what is actually causing the issue.

**NOTE** A lot of this answer assumes you are using webpack to bundle code. However if that is not the case you will need to search out optimization and bundle analyzed for the specific bundling tool you are using